# regex issue with numbers (python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a string thath goes like that:

```
<123, 321>
```

the range of the numbers can be between `0` to `999`.

I need to insert those coordinates as fast as possible into two variables, so i thought about regex. I've already splitted the string to two parts and now i need to isolate the integer from all the other characters.
I've tried this pattern:

```
 ^-?[0-9]+$
```

but the output is:

```
[]
```

any help? :)

Comment: Maybe just take two substrings: one from 1 to the position of the , and the other from the position of the comma + 2 to the end of the string - 1.

Comment: regex is probably slower than you think

Answer (score 2):

If your strings follow the same format `<123, 321>` then this should be a little bit faster than regex approach

```
def str_translate(s):
    return s.translate(None, " <>").split(',')

In [52]: str_translate("<123, 321>")
Out[52]: ['123', '321']
```

Comment: If the `<>` are always in the same place, `s[1: -1]` will be slightly quicker than the `translate`. You can split on `', '` if you need to get rid of the space.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to get rid of the anchors( `^` and `$`)

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "<123, 321>"
>>> re.findall(r"-?[0-9]+", string)
['123', '321']
>>>
```

**Note** `^` `$` Anchors at the start and end  of patterns `-?[0-9]+` ensures that the string consists only of digits.

That is the regex engine attempts to match the pattern from the start of the string, `^` using `-?[0-9]+` till the end of the string `$`.  But it fails because `<` cannot be matched by `-?[0-9]+`

Where as the [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) will find all substrings that match the pattern `-?[0-9]+`, that is the digits.

Comment: "the string consists only of strings"? your answer is correct but that part was confusing even for a regex veteran

Comment: @oxymor0n Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: Your note is just... confusing, that's all. Removing the anchors is correct, but your note on why that is doesn't really explain the problem.

Comment: That was a typo i actually meant *ensures that the string consists only of digits*. Is it still unclear, I will edit if so. please do mention

Answer (score 0):

`"^-?[0-9]+$"` will only match a string that contains a number and nothing else.

You want to match a group and the extract that group:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile("(-?[0-9]+)")
>>> pattern.findall("<123, 321>")
['123', '321']
```